# Spring Production

Tags: java, spring-boot

Доброго времени суток, есть проект на spring boot, написал rest-сервер, все собирается gradle`ом в JAR, связь с mongodb, все работает, но не могу понять как использовать в продакшене, тоесть где что прописать что бы поменять порт подключения и адрес и тп, или это делается на арендованной машине(VPS).

Comment: IMHO вопрос слишком "широкий". У всех разные продакшны и советы будут тоже разные.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin я понимаю, но мне нужно понять в какую сторону копать, мне нужно писать какой то конфиг если да то как, или может это делается на вирт машине

Comment: Попробуйте действовать по необходимости, если не знаете в какую сторону копать. Начинаете устанавливать приложение на сервер и по мере появления вопросов, решаете их. Например, как сменить порт, как указать другие настройки БД, как сделать, чтобы сервис после рестарта сервера запускался и прочее-прочее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На серверах обычно принято разделять Front-end и Back-end для Web приложений. В вашем случае Back-end'ом является само приложение, сделанное с использованием Spring Boot. В качестве Front-end можно использовать Nginx или Apache Http Server. Такой подход дает возможность изменять порты и адреса доступа для ресурсов на вашем сервере, кешировать статический контент и т.д. 
Например если на вашем сервере есть 2 web приложения, каждое из которых привязано к своему порту (допустим 8080 и 8085), то с помощью Nginx вы сможете организовать доступ по стандартному 80 порту используя разные URL'ы для каждого из приложений (http://localhost/app1 и http://localhost/app2).
Front-End можно назвать дополнительным уровнем абстракции который дает гибкость в конфигурировании инфраструктуры вашего сервера.

Comment: просто не мог понять, какие манипуляции нужно сделать после аренды VPS что бы можно было сделать connect к моему rest, я так понял нужно просто настроить Nginx?

Comment: @newakkoff ваш вопрос действительно слишком не конкретный. Для примера могу описать стандартную конфигурацию серверов в нашей компании:
1. Первым делом настраивается фаервол (iptables) по принципу запрещено все кроме нужных портов и протоколов (для http это 80 и 443).
2. Доступ на сервер по ssh открыт только на определенные ip;
3. В качестве Front-end настраивается nginx;
4. Все необходимое для работы приложений окружение устанавливается с помощью Docker контейнеров (web сервер, БД и т.п.)

Comment: этот rest я буду использовать для android приложения что бы получать данные из бд в json, и я не знаю как это организовать

Comment: вторая часть этой статьи должна вам помочь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/257223/